# Wordpress authentication for a custom page with access to plugin data

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, session-cookies, gravity-forms-plugin

First, I am a Wordpress Noob. My company builds custom data dashboards. Our client wants to integrate our dashboard into Wordpress. They use plugins, mainly Gravity forms and WooCommerce, from which the dashboard needs to retrieve data.

The dashboard will be build as a custom page (HTML/JS/CSS) and we plan to served it as a Wordpress static item (like: https://qodeinteractive.com/magazine/add-custom-html-page-to-wordpress/).

Ideally, it would work like this:

1. the clients' user logs in into Wordpress.
2. Within the Wordpress environment the user can click a button to open our dashboard.
3. The dashboard fetches the data from Wordpress / a Wordpress API and displays it.

The complexity starts with the last step, how can we access the data from Wordpress/Gravity forms/WooCommerce. I would prefer it, if the user does not have to login separately into our dashboard, but that the credentials provided in Wordpress can be used.

There are API's available for Wordpress/Ggravity forms/WooCommerce, but I am unsure about the authentication part.

I found something about cookie authentication (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication), but I am not sure *if* this would work or  *how* this works. The information is related to PHP, while we will be using HTML/JS.

Are there other options available?

I know it is a broad question, but I hope to get some pointers to how to deal with this.

Comment: Use the WC Rest Api. You can make any call from JS.

Comment: Yes, JS can make a call to a Rest API. What I am really after is the authentication part.

Comment: In this case you can write your own REST API endpoint with custom authentication. If this would help I can show you how.

Comment: @Mr.Jo , if you have an example (the show me how) than that would be really helpful.

Comment: What type of data are you trying to pull ? I feel like you're making things way harder than they should be. You can create a custom page and restrict the page access to a specific user role. Then you simply pull any data to the page. Be a bit more specific in regards to what is the problem you're facing.

Comment: As I understand, you made a fancy looking full on HTML statistical static dashboard, and you want to make it dynamic with data from WordPress?

Comment: @amarinediary that is indeed what is going on. 
A fancy page which needs to be fed with data from Wordpress and it’s plugins. So how does the (test) api know the user and if it is authenticated?

Comment: You don't need to get the data via API most of it can be access via the `WP_Query` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/.